# How to import files that are not included in the project by checking that they do not exist?

Tags: unity, file, import

I want to check whether the files exist, as in the window that opens when importing asset from `Package Manager`, and copy them into the `Assets` folder.

[image: 1]

`FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory` method does not meet my request. If the file path exists, it gives an error; if the same files exist in a different file path, it copies them.

```
FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory("Assets/Source","Assets/Destination");
```

Scripts, materials, scenes, etc. in the file path. I want it to look at the `GUID` value in the `.meta` file, not the names of the files.

Comment: Presumably you considered opening the .meta file you wanted to copy, reading its GUID, then using the AssetDatabase to check if there's already an asset with that GUID? What went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: I cannot access the `GUID` value of files that are not included in the project with `AssetDatabase.GUIDFromAssetPath`. For example; 
source file path: `"Assets/MyProject/Samples~/MySample"` 
target file path: `"Assets/MySample"`

Comment: No, you cannot, that's why you open and read the text of the file using System.IO methods, naturally.